# php socket functions not found

Tags: php, sockets, command-line

Hezy, Im trying to use socket programming, I need a background service. I tried a simple example:

```
 if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
     echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
```

if I try it in the browsers, it works...
but with php.exe on command line, it doesnt work... it says `socket_create()` doesn't exists. But sockets are enabled. Now what? I dont have another php.ini in Windows directory

Comment: Are you sure the php_sockets.dll file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line php.exe might use another php.ini than the php module that's used by Apache, so the sockets extension isn't loaded for command line.

Try executing `php.exe -i` to see which php.ini it's using, and enable the appropriate extension in there.

Comment: the same. I copied there my php.ini, it dropes a tons of warnings, and fails

Comment: it was easyphp (its like WAMPP). It holds two php.ini, one of is the main and the other is a copy with little modifications. I just had to copy one of them to the Windows directory.